Error 'cannot coerce class ‘"call"’ to a data.frame' in R
Is there a way to turn a call into a vector in R?
I have a call that I got from completing an ANOVA
> final.test.result.type
aov(formula = Value ~ STATION, data = df)

I want to turn the call "final.test.result.type" into a vector that contains a row with the 'call' as a written statement

Your question is quite unclear. The answer deparses the call into a character string and a character vector is an atomic vector. However, if you want to store one or several calls in a data structure, you need to put them into a vector of mode "expression": e <- vector(mode = "expression", length = 1L); e[[1]] <- final.test.result.type$call

Alternatively, if the goal is storing calls in a data.frame, you could just store them in a list column: DF <- data.frame(x = 1); DF$e = list(final.test.result.type$call)

I would do this:

Create a minimal example (ask me if anything here is an incorrect assumption)

# fake data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Value = rnorm(10),
  STATION = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 5)
)

# the function
final.test.result.type <- aov(Value ~ STATION, data = df)


Extract the call as a vector

call_vector <- deparse(final.test.result.type$call)

Note the "[1]" in the output, it is a unidimensional vector
> call_vector
[1] "aov(formula = Value ~ STATION, data = df)"

